# Get/download your app's crash report

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, crash

Once you've deployed your app on your device, and wander away from Xcode, it suddenly crashes under some circumstances. How do you retrieve the crash log?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna manage crash report, you should use Fabric.
It's free and get crash report real time. Powered by Twitter. Very cool.

https://get.fabric.io

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works for apps released. However, during development time, crash reporting tools are generally avoided, as they result in a longer build time.

Comment: So you can view Device Logs as judepereira said

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your device to your Mac
2. In Xcode 7.x, go to **Window** -> **Devices**
3. In the Devices window, select your device by it's name in the left
4. Now, on the right, below your device information, hit the **View Device Logs** button
5. Select your app name in the left, and the crash log appears in the right panel
6. To export this crash log, simply right click on the entry in the left, and select **Export log**

Comment: And where does it put the file?